# UITouchType for iOS9.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch, 3dtouch

iOS introduced UITouchType in iOS9 which provides the UITouchTypeStylus constant. Will this constant only work for 3D touch device like iPad Pro or is it available on any iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touchtype stylus will only be "fired" when you are using it on a supported device. Here are some links which will help you further [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TouchCanvas/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016561-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), [2](http://www.russbishop.net/uitouchtypestylus), [3](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-track-finger-position-and-touch-force-in-ios-9/)...

Comment: What are the supported devices? Are older iPad/iPhones supported?

Comment: Supported devices for the stylus? Curently only the iPad Pro as you have written

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, only iPad pro supports Apple pencil which is UITouchTypeStylus in code.